# Eloquent ORM querying relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Let's say I have two tables like this:

```
users:
    - id
    - username

profiles:
    - user_id
    - name
```

Using datamapper ORM codeigniter I could write a query like this:

```
$users = new User();
$users->where_related('profile', 'name', 'Diego');
$users->get();
```

and it will return the users with the profile name Diego. How can I achieve this using Eloquent ORM? I know how to do this using fluent(pure sql) but have no idea how to do this using eloquent.

**Edit:** I solved this issue using this query but it feels dirty, is there a better way to do this?

```
$users = Users::join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'user.id')->where('profiles.name', 'Diego')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create models for each table, then specify the relationship.

```
<?php
class User {
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'users';
    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Profile');
    }
}
class Profile {
    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
    protected $table = 'profiles';
}
$user = User::where('username', 'Diego')->get();
// Or eager load...
$user = User::with('Profile')->where('username', 'Diego')->get();
?>
```

The Laravel docs make the process very clear:  http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships.

Note that the Fluent methods are available to Eloquent and can be chained, e.g. where()->where()->orderBy()->etc....

Comment: With your answer I wrote this query:

    User::with('profile')->where('name', 'Diego")->get();

But it is returning this error:
    SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from users where name = ?) (Bindings: array ( 0 => 'Diego', ))

Comment: All the queries here will be run on the Users table and not the profile relationship. This is not what the OP wants.